# Prediction of more characters by SOLR-Spellchecking

Tags: solr

I want to implement an autocomplete function with SOLR-Spellchecker in the way Google have implemented it. For example if I type in "chocol", I get the suggestions "chocolate", "chocolissimo", "chocolate cake", ...
This means SOLR would add more than one character to the typed in term.

This is my SOLR configuration:

```
{
  "searchComponent":{
    "name": "spellcheckXXX",
    "class": "solr.SpellCheckComponent",
    "queryAnalyzerFieldType": "text_general",
    "spellchecker": {
        "name": "default",
        "field": "multi_term_lowercase_suggestion",
        "classname": "solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker",
        "distanceMeasure": "internal",
        "maxEdits":1,
        "minPrefix":1,
        "minQueryLength":3,
        "combineWords": "true",
        "comparatorClass": "freq"
    }
}


{
  "requestHandler":{
    "name":"/spellcheckXXX",
    "class":"solr.SearchHandler",
    "startup":"lazy",
    "defaults":{
        "spellcheck":"true",
        "spellcheck.dictionary":"default",
        "spellcheck.extendedResults":"true",
        "spellcheck.count":"50",
        "spellcheck.alternativeTermCount":"2",
        "spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest":"50",
        "spellcheck.collate":"true",
        "spellcheck.collateExtendedResults":"true",
        "spellcheck.maxCollationTries":"100",
        "spellcheck.maxCollations":"50",
        "spellcheck.onlyMorePopular":"true",
        "rows": 0,
        "df": "multi_term_lowercase_suggestion"
    },
    "last-components":["spellcheckXXX"]
}


<field name="multi_term_lowercase_suggestion" type="multi_term_lowercase_suggestion_text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>


<fieldType name="multi_term_lowercase_suggestion_text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

My problem is with my configuations, that I only get suggestions, which have added only one character or the characters in the term are replaced by others. Not really a predctions, more like a spelling correction.

So if the term is "Schoko" (in German: Schokolade means chocolate) the result is (.../spellcheckCLN?q=Schokol):

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 0,
        "start": 0,
        "numFoundExact": true,
        "docs": []
    },
    "spellcheck": {
        "suggestions": [
            "schokol",
            {
                "numFound": 2,
                "startOffset": 0,
                "endOffset": 7,
                "origFreq": 0,
                "suggestion": [
                    {
                        "word": "school",
                        "freq": 41
                    },
                    {
                        "word": "schoko",
                        "freq": 13
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "correctlySpelled": false,
        "collations": [
            "collation",
            {
                "collationQuery": "school",
                "hits": 21,
                "misspellingsAndCorrections": [
                    "schokol",
                    "school"
                ]
            },
            "collation",
            {
                "collationQuery": "schoko",
                "hits": 9,
                "misspellingsAndCorrections": [
                    "schokol",
                    "schoko"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If the term is "Schokolad" (.../spellcheckCLN?q=Schokolad):

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 1
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 0,
        "start": 0,
        "numFoundExact": true,
        "docs": []
    },
    "spellcheck": {
        "suggestions": [
            "schokolad",
            {
                "numFound": 1,
                "startOffset": 0,
                "endOffset": 9,
                "origFreq": 0,
                "suggestion": [
                    {
                        "word": "schokolade",
                        "freq": 34
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "correctlySpelled": false,
        "collations": [
            "collation",
            {
                "collationQuery": "schokolade",
                "hits": 25,
                "misspellingsAndCorrections": [
                    "schokolad",
                    "schokolade"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So there is a result for "Schokolade" but not suggested when the term is shorter by more than one character. What I have  to change?

Comment: _Generally_ the spell checker is intended to detect when a word among many in your query can be misspelled, and `schoko` and `school` is closer to a misspelling of your query than what `schokolade` is - (one wrong letter compared to four). Have you considered using the suggester functionality which was designed for your use case instead? https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/suggester.html

Comment: Yes the suggester function of SOLR was our first approach, but our result were documents, not terms. Maybe this is caused by our SOLR setup. So because of this we switched to the TermComponent and later to SpellChecking.

Comment: "MoreLikeThis" is the component that gives documents back, you should get terms with the suggester as shown in the example with weights: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/suggester.html#example-usages - you can also create a separate suggestion index where a document equals a valid suggestion and then query against those.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In the end we switched to the search component and used faceting for the suggestions. In this way we could also filter the documents. This page discribes the configuration good: https://solr.pl/en/2013/03/25/autocomplete-on-multivalued-fields-using-faceting/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem, so I will close this question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).